# EXM email links throw potentially dangerous request error

Tags: exm

Our application is on Sitecore 9.0.2

We have configured a list of Internal links in our Email(Header)

[image]

The Link on the email is getting generated as shown below:-

```
https://{hostname}/sitecore%20modules/Web/EXM/RedirectUrlPage.aspx?ec_eq=BJSDUnAPW4zW41C87Bv71%2bUzlfoyPY6pcn9gZeQjKT3Tmq4fThnqsDk8%2fez9OQJgbWVEXc8x9mfGM6rZo8MQp5Q6xB1lKqi1%2b6L2W7TCoK5FkUgu8WVY8qNxjqDj2io%2bWzGkchqGleSfuohPCCiK%2fQ04Do%2bqauo9cA7Q%2bKhUT%2fOG%2fRQvUGwGneR%2f%2fD3sULcIAQAqTcWbIrgCZE2swDCdFBnJOrjbkyrvoJhjypGSwLhMvKPCBQ%2b0qXVnKBfLe4fsaCKLF8EW7aTKb2v8NzkKLjUSMytMN0sPQrbbRQJx3IoYlUAaUD4z%2b7Q236MQSjBK4j3r%2ffVfJjITSj%2fsVLYwlPVAPlQQD3QYW4tIIUvb5VkysE%2feIITbjS8wKgVkYKUgF0kCWq53wKDNY4qcB4Y4sOLFn%2f6EjuOHnLoCN9KPSOt%2fOL7zoIKtLhJ7yF%2b9hY1Pldv6HEgZuxnqQnK%2bSqmPk%2bbm0pPx%2b3wRLDCegtsvprTq1C5qS8QSJViR1TTAWOV%2bneBYiM4I9GkSyMYysnAb3lHhtOwCogdFPTApAmzdEl%2btua8KzvN9igNC00ErfVjmTBJ1qFoVEr0KN1NcscD3ygmC8NvXTh3puzZA%2bDwFG4I%3d
```

The link generated is not getting resolved as expected , it throws a potentially dangerous request error on click

[image]

Am i missing anything ?

Comment: You can fix it by adding requestPathInvalidCharacters="" attribute in <httpRuntime> node of web.config. See https://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx for details.

Comment: Hi @x3mxray , thanks for your reply , should'nt this be working OOTB ? instead of us changing the web.config?

Comment: Hi @x3mxray , thanks for your reply , should'nt this be working OOTB ? instead of us changing the web.config?

Comment: Yes, it should work OOTB. It may be problem with url encoding/decoding or incorrect web.config settings. You should find the reason, I just suggest a fix. Does this issue reproduced when you request http instead of https?